# Using [NSObject load] to initialized system with no autorelease pool

Tags: ios, autorelease

I am writing an iPad application using the Xcode 4.3.2 and the iOS simulator. I have a series of classes that I want to register with a singleton at start up so that other classes can request services through that singleton that are provided by these registered classes.

To effect this behavior I have been relying on overriding the **load** class method on NSObject. However, I discovered that all the code that gets executed by the **load** method occurs outside the main function before there is any opportunity to set up an autorelease pool. I'm using some 3rd party technology in my application that current prohibits the use or automatic reference counting, so I need to rely on an autorelease pool to help manage the lifetime of created objects.

During the registration process, a number of messages appear in the debug console for the simulator complaining about autorelease being called with no autorelease pool. One of these is related to a dictionary allocated by the singleton. Other are related to block objects that get copied from the stack and store in that singleton dictionary.

It is not clear to me how serious these debug messages are. I suspect the allocation of the dictionary may not be problematic as the singleton should exist for the lifetime of the application and that dictionary will likely never be released. Likewise the block stored in the dictionary should persist as well, so I'm wondering if I don't need to bother calling autorelease on them after calling the **copy** method.

Or maybe there is another way to accomplish what I want with out having to resort to the current technique that might be less problematic

What can people suggest about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should have better luck overriding `+[NSObject initialize]` rather than `load`, `initialize` is called the first time the class is referenced, rather than when the image the class is in is loaded. This will give you better handing of all this.

Comment: I don't think that will work for my purposes. I want the object to automatically register themselves with the singleton. Nothing is going to be referencing the object to invoke the initialize method. The load method gets called whether the objects have been used yet or not.

Comment: Then setup your own pools in the load methods

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is to use `dispatch_once_t`, which is only executed once per runtime, across all threads:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static SingletonClass *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not following things correctly. If I understand the code above, it looks like it is meant to help enforce the singleton pattern. I already have a solution to that, although the code above looks a much simpler approach. My concern isn't about enforcing the singleton. The problem is that when the singleton is first needed, there is no autorelease pool available because object are trying to automatically register with it by use of the +load method, which gets call for each class before the main function executes.